# excel - If formula conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a report and I have attached the picture.

I have used the formula  `=IF(B2=C2, "True","False")`.   Column B and C includes text values and if they are similar then true or else false.

However I have to add a certain condition to the above formula. When in column B text value "Sign off pending" = Column C text value "Completed", I want it to appear as true.

I want to include the above condition in existing  `=IF(B2=C2, "True","False")`. How do I do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR and AND:

```
=IF(OR(B2=C2,AND(B2="Sign off pending",C2="Completed")), "True","False")
```

Just an FYI: TRUE/FALSE will be returned by:

```
=OR(B2=C2,AND(B2="Sign off pending",C2="Completed"))
```

But if your version is not English it will return the equivalent in the local language.  So if you want `True`,`False` in English regardless of local settings, use the first.  If it does not matter the shortened will suffice.

Comment: think you're missing an opening quote mark

Comment: @akarshvinayramu if this answered your question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: np, happens to me all the time :)